# Two if statements, both working separately but not together, PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, custom-fields

I'm working in WordPress with in an extension for Woo commerce. I have two custom fields on the checkout page which are both saving and reporting notices when the user input value either exists in the database and another when it doesn't. Both of these fields work on their own but when both are active only the first condition throws an error no matter which field is entered.

The code I'm working with

```
// process the checkout
function jm_custom_checkout_field_process() {

        // Access the database 
        global $wpdb; 

        // query the database
        $meta_key = '_create_new_group';
        $groupnames = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT meta_value 
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
            WHERE meta_key = %s" 
            ,$meta_key
        ));

        // get value from user
        $newgroupname = $_POST['create_new_group'];

        // get value from user
        $existing_groupname = $_POST['add_to_existing_group'];

        // check if user input is in array
        if( in_array($newgroupname, $groupnames ) ) {
           wc_add_notice( __( 'Group name already taken.' ), 'error' );
        }
        // check if user input is in array 
        if( ! in_array($existing_groupname, $groupnames ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Group name does not exist.' ), 'error' );
        }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'jm_custom_checkout_field_process');


// save the extra field when checkout is processed
function jm_save_extra_checkout_fields( $order_id, $posted ){

    // Check if there is user input and save
    if( isset( $posted['add_to_existing_group'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_create_new_group', sanitize_text_field( $posted['add_to_existing_group'] ) );            
        }    

        // Check if there is user input and save
    if( isset( $posted['create_new_group'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_create_new_group', sanitize_text_field( $posted['create_new_group'] ) );//
    } 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'jm_save_extra_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I couldn't find any good documentation on `wc_add_notice()`, but I bet it only allows one notice per request.

Comment: maybe you only output the first notice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a call to `wc_add_notice()` results in exiting the exeuction path, you could try something like:

```
$blnShowFirstNotice = false;
$blnShowSecondNotice = false;

// check if user input is in array
if ($newgroupname) 
{
    if( in_array($newgroupname, $groupnames ) ) 
    {
       $blnShowFirstNotice = true;
    }
}
// check if user input is in array 
if ($existing_groupname) 
{
    if( !in_array($existing_groupname, $groupnames ) ) 
    {
        $blnShowSecondNotice = true;
    }
}

if($blnShowFirstNotice==true && $blnShowSecondNotice==false)
{
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Group name already taken.' ), 'error' );
}
else if($blnShowFirstNotice==false && $blnShowSecondNotice==true)
{           
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Group name does not exist.' ), 'error' );
}
else if($blnShowFirstNotice==true && $blnShowSecondNotice==true)
{
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Group name already taken.' . 'Group name does not exist.' ), 'error' );
}
```

Comment: that were also my thoughts, but at least `wc_add_notice` doesn't exit the code: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_add_notice.html#56-75

Comment: From what I understand the condition is also checking for an empty input? So it throws an error as it can't find an empty value in the database under the particular key?

Comment: @John-EW, I honestly don't know anything about WooCommerce or wc_add_notice...this is just the first thing I would try to get around it.

Comment: What you provided was great, thank you. I'm new and this was quite a lot for me to put together, I knew it was something like that but couldn't get there at this point. I updated your answer as the code needed to check if there was any value input at all, that was it, it now works how I want it to. Thanks again